# How to remove things from drywall?

Tags: drywall-anchor

How do I remove the little round plates that are back of a stud in drywall?

Comment: Can you post a photo of what you're taking about, and/or provide a better description.?

Answer (score 1):

I get a flat screw driver and tap them with a hammer until it is about 1/8" inside drywall.  Then just a bit of spackle over the indention.

Comment: or, for a smaller hole, you can drill off  the cap. But, yes, spackle and paint.